# the fastest way to compute adjacent edge list (as_adj_edge_list)

Tags: r, igraph

This problem almost drives me crazy. First say I have a sample **directed** graph like:

```
g <- sample_gnp(20000, 0.1, directed = T)
```

Now I want to compute the proportion of "mutual edges" for one's all outgoing edges. This is the fastest way that comes to my mind:

```
ael <- as_adj_edge_list(graph, mode = "out")
sapply(ael, function(x) {mean(which_mutual(g, x))})
```

However, the `as_adj_edge_list` function seems to take endless time. My real data has about 23k vertices and 110k edges so I cannot just set and wait for the code to finish. Besides, from a search of SO posts, I find that `as_adj_edge_list` is already the fastest way to iterate over vertices or edges. So am I using it the stupid way? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mutual egdes correspond to the edges of an undirected version `g.undir` of the graph `g.dir`, provided the conversion mode is "mutual". Then the proportion of mutual edges among the outgoing edges is found as the ratio

> degree in g.undir / 'outgoing'-degree in g.dir

```
library(igraph)

g.dir <- sample_gnp(1000, 0.1, directed = T)

#-----------------------------------------

system.time(
{
  ael <- as_adj_edge_list(g.dir, mode = "out")
  A <- sapply(ael, function(x) {mean(which_mutual(g.dir, x))})

})

#-----------------------------------------

system.time(
{
  g.undir <- as.undirected(g.dir,mode="mutual")   
  d.dir <- degree(g.dir,mode="out")
  d.undir <- degree(g.undir)

  B <- d.undir/d.dir
})

identical(A,B)
```

.

```
> library(igraph)

> g.dir <- sample_gnp(1000, 0.1, directed = T)

> #-----------------------------------------
> 
> system.time(
+ {
+   ael <- as_adj_edge_list(g.dir, mode = "out")
+   A <- sapply(ael, function(x) { .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  11.93    0.00   12.04 

> #-----------------------------------------
> 
> system.time(
+ {
+   g.undir <- as.undirected(g.dir,mode="mutual")   
+   d.dir <- degree(g.dir,mode .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 

> identical(A,B)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: brillient! your answer avoid iterating over vertices and vectorize the algorithm! just one more question, why `degree()` is so much faster than `as_adj_edge_list()`? should i avoid using `as_adj_edge_list()` as much as possible?

Comment: Since I didn't develop the `igraph` package, I can only guess why `as_adj_edge_list` is that slow.
It is much more memory consuming than the `degree` function of course and memory management can be time consuming. The edge list `as_adj_edge_list` still contains the whole structure of the graph. But `degree` produces a comperatively small vector whose size is known in advance, one numeric value for each vertex.
I won't condemn `as_adj_edge_list` wholesale. Always check out some options and pick the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explaination, I've already accepted it. You really helped me out! :)